# mongodb retrieve documnets sorting by fixed order

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I want to implement a requirement that "retrieving some records with specific condition first then record with other condition second and then other ..."

Let's say there is a collection contains those documents:

```
{
   name:"tour in beijing for one night",
   fee: 500,
   cityId: 5010

},
{
   name:"vistit in shanghai for one night with food",
   fee: 700,
   cityId: 4011

},
{
   name:"tour in beijing for tow days",
   fee: 900,
   cityId: 5010

},
{
   name:"vistit in shanghai for one night",
   fee: 450,
   cityId: 4011

},
{
   name:"visit kuangchou for one day",
   fee: 400,
   cityId: 3013
},
{
   name:"tour in beijing with food",
   fee: 1000,
   cityId: 5010
}
```

And I want to know if there is a *elegant* way of doing this:

- I want the records with cityId `5010` to be retrieved first, with the sort of `fee` ASC. And then the cityId `4011`(also with the sort of `fee` ASC)(But it's acceptable if can't do the ASC sorting at one time, but bulk of records sorting by different cityId is highly wanted).

For this specific sample data I want the query result to be in as this order(if I gave a cityId order of `[5010,4011,3013]` as sorting condition) *Note that the cityId may be in other **mixed** order, the descending order of this example is just a happily coincident*:

```
// beijing with cityId 5010 will be retrieved first with fee ASC
{
   name:"tour in beijing for one night",
   fee: 500,
   cityId: 5010

},
{
   name:"tour in beijing for tow days",
   fee: 900,
   cityId: 5010

},
{
   name:"tour in beijing with food",
   fee: 1000,
   cityId: 5010
},
// then comes shanghai with cityId of 4011
{
   name:"vistit in shanghai for one night",
   fee: 450,
   cityId: 4011

},
{
   name:"vistit in shanghai for one night with food",
   fee: 700,
   cityId: 4011

},
// then kuangzhou
{
   name:"visit kuangchou for one day",
   fee: 400,
   cityId: 3013
}
```

Will that be doable with just one query? I think there should be a sort condition, but how to write that sort condition?

Comment: you mean you want to have all the documents with same `cityId` after each other, and locally sorted by `fee`?

Comment: @n9code yes,and  also the order of the `cityId` should be manipulate-able.

Comment: I think you would have to break it down into a query per cityId. Then inside that you can sort by fee.

Comment: @armnotstrong can you bring an example of such **manipulation**?

Comment: @RyanMcCaffery It's what I implement it now, but I wonder if there is a better way of doing this, because with no idea of the record counts of each cityId, pagination can be a disaster :-(

Comment: @n9code sorry for the confusion, I mean the order of bulks of the cities can be differ. like `[4011,3013,5010]`

Comment: @armnotstrong correct me if I'm wrong. You want bulks of documents for specific `cityId`s, and require that the order of `cityId` bulks must be controlable?

Comment: @n9code yes, you got that right, and orders in every bulk could be controlable will get a bonus :-)

Comment: is the size of bulk dynamic? or there are always fixed 3 `cityId`s you want in a bulk?

Comment: @n9code yes, it's dynamic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78295/discussion-between-n9code-and-armnotstrong).

Answer (score 0):

By using a Aggregation Pipeline Operators. Documents pass through the stages in sequence. So you could do a $match on cityID, then a $sort on each group.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: { cityId: { $in: [5010, 4011] } }
}, {
  $sort: { fee: -1 }
})
```

Coding in the dark so I can't test. Might need to group too.

```
db.collection.aggregate( {$match: ...}, {$group: ...}, {$sort: ...} )
```

This will definitely be in the right direction.

**Previous Answer:**

Use $in

```
db.collection.find({"cityId": {"$in": ["5010", "4011"]}}).sort({"fee": 1})
```

[image]

Read more: http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/

Comment: Seems that the origin order on the left is what I wanted, I will dig into the blog you mentioned and see if I can find something. thanks for advice though.

Comment: Do you mean that if I make a index of the cityId then what I want will be meet for granted?

Comment: Yes, if you need to index the cityId. Though I would look into the performance difference with db.collection.find().explain() or db.collection.find( { .... , $explain: 1 } ) as to get the diagram on the left, you  will be doing a full in memory scan.

Comment: But seems that the order will not be **control-able** this way if we make the `cityId` indexed.

Comment: Updated my answer. In the right direction @armnotstrong